# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have tried to select all records from a table from date1 to date2, Example Jun 28, 2014 to Jan 05, 2015, for display. Basically, sort out selected records based on date criteria. Big thanks if anyone could point out my mistake.

What I tried to do here is allowed user to select specific dates from calendar to view the records

I have gone through all answers, but still couldn't find similar solution to mine. I think, there may be some error in my syntax.

```
sqlDateRangeSearch = "Select * from BatteryDataTable where ((BatteryDateChanged) <= ""*" & Me.FromDTPicker.Value & "*"")" & " and ((BatteryDateChanged) <= " & """*" & Me.ToDTPicker.Value & "*""));"

Me.RecordSource = sqlDateRangeSearch
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have wildcard characters in the search criteria for the query. If using dates, you'll want to avoid those. Also, you don't need quotes for dates in access queries. If you're dynamically creating SQL I'd use something like:

```
sqlDateRangeSearch = "Select * from BatteryDataTable where (BatteryDateChanged <= #" & Me.FromDTPicker.Value & "#)" & " and (BatteryDateChanged <= #" & Me.ToDTPicker.Value & "#));"
```

Just a side note, your comparison operators are the same. I think you want it to say something like (remember the "#" symbols):

```
...WHERE (Field1 >= #Date1# AND Field1 < #Date2#);
```

Hope that helps!